# PHP Symfony Build All Propel Fails - MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, symfony1, propel, symfony-1.4

I have just set up a completely new Symfony 1.4 project and designed the schema but unfortunately I can't build the schema.

I having some trouble with the symfony command `php symfony propel:build --all --no-confirmation`.

Unfortunately it leaves a rather cryptic error message `php symfony propel:build --all --no-confirmation` does anyone know what is causing this error and how to correct it? Google turns up some polish websites that (even with translate) I cannot understand!

Many thanks!

Full Error:

```
>> schema    putting /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/swingers/config/generated-schema.xml
>> propel    Running "insert-sql" phing task
Execution of target "insert-sql" failed for the following reason: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/swingers/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfPropelPlugin/lib/vendor/propel-generator/build-propel.xml:272:1:  [wrapped: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory]
    [phing] /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/swingers/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfPropelPlugin/lib/vendor/propel-generator/build-propel.xml:272:1:  [wrapped: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory]

  Some problems occurred when executing the task:                                       

  build-propel.xml:272:1:  [wrapped: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory]  

  If the exception message is not clear enough, read the output of the task for         
  more information                                                                      

>> file-     /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/swingers/config/generated-schema.xml
PezCuckowMBP:swingers pezcuckow$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Damn, I've answered my own question after some more thought:

I am using Xampp on OSX 10.6. The problem is it was executing the wrong php binary.

```
$ php symfony propel:insert-sql
```

would call the php binary in `/usr/bin/` not the one in

`/Applications/xampp/xamppfiles/bin/` which is what I wanted in the first place

The command $ php is running the wrong PHP (OSX's default PHP).

To resolve this problem I:

Went in `/usr/bin` and renamed

```
php to php_old
phpize to phpize_old 
php-config to php-config_old
```

Then, make symbolic link:

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/php-config php-config
sudo ln -s /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/php php
sudo ln -s /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/phpize phpize
```

Hope this is of use to someone else stuck!